# Перегрузка оператора << в C++

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, String const& s)
{
    ostream& out << s.s;
    return out;
}
```

s - char*

Ошибка:
Reference to type 'std::basic_ostream' must be initialized

Как правильно написать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ostream& out << s.s;`  Вы говорите: `out` это ссылька на `ostream`(ссылька на какой обьект?) Это вновь обьявленная ссылька, хоть и имеет то же имя, что аргумент функции. В аргументе в уже говорили, что  это ссылька на обьект типа  `ostream`, который вы передадите в функцию. Так что просто используйте ее:

```
out << s.s;
```

и еще:

не `String const& s`, а  `const String& s`

Comment: Касательно «ещё»: у людей разный стиль; тот, что Вы указали ничем не лучше того, что использовал автор.

Comment: @ixSci,  принципиально  вы правы, но  есть такие понятия, как читабельность  и общепринятый стиль...

Comment: Такого понятия как «общепринятый стиль» не существует, по крайней мере в C++.  И этот вариант часто встречается в коде у людей, т.к. `String const&` соответствует правилу чтения типа в C++: ссылка на константный String.